# Calculating the depth of a tree data structure - clojure

Tags: clojure, s-expression, zipper

I'm trying to implement an algorithm to find the depth of a sequence expression through Clojure Zippers.

```
(zip/seq-zip (+ 1 (* 2 3)))
```

This is the way I'm interpreting a sequence to be converted into a tree data structure. Is there a direct method to calculate this through Zipper library(the depth to be calculated as 2, from the given example)?

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: My suggestion would be to not use zippers, they are making the matter more complicated. `(fn depth [x] (if (seq? x) (reduce max 0 (map depth x)) 0))`. A zipper solution would we littered with movement commands, burying the lede.

Comment: That will always return 0. (fn depth [x d] (if (seq? x) (apply max (map #(depth % (inc d)) x)) d)). d should be initially 0.

Comment: @turingcomplete true, thanks -- that's what I get for not testing code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following recursive approach:

```
(defn height [s-expr]
  (if-let [sub-trees (seq (filter coll? s-expr))]
    (inc
     (apply max
            (map height sub-trees)))
    0))


=> (height '(+ 1 (* 2 3)))
=> 1
```

Effectively the above treats collections as branches and everything else as leaves. You can replace `coll?` with any other branch definition (e.g. `list?`) that fits your needs.

Comment: As ```height``` is a single argument form, you could set the recursive map as ```(map height sub-trees)```

Comment: FYI. `(apply max (map f s))` can be replaced with `(apply max-key f s) if `f` returns a number.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to compute both the minimum and maximum heights of a tree.
In that case you can extend [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31268114/3165711) to include a `comp` function argument to determine that selection criteria.

```clj
;; Compute the height (either min or max, according to the `comp` function)
;; of the tree `tree`. Trees must be expressed as nested sequences.
(defn height
  [tree comp]
  (if (coll? tree)
    (inc (apply comp (map #(height % comp) tree)))
    0))

(defn max-height [tree] (height tree max))
(defn min-height [tree] (height tree min))
```